# Does Vim support highlight range of lines via python-plugin

Tags: python, vim

I am looking for a way to highlight range of lines in vim through python-plugin.
I went through document but not got clear idea.
Is it supported or not ? If yes, please let me know the way to use it.

Thanks,
~Rohit

Comment: Vim allows plugins to be developed in vim script as well as languages like perl and python. Vim script is easy as well with set of preloaded functions

Comment: Thanks for providing input.

Comment: Sure you can, f.i.: `:py vim.command("call matchaddpos('error', range(30, 33))")`.  However, that is just a roundabout way of running the corresponding Vim function directly: `:call matchaddpos('error', range(30, 33))`.  Perhaps you should describe the problem you're trying to solve, rather than the solution you see to it?